# HList/KList from class values

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I want to be able to create a class/trait that behaves somewhat like an enumeration (`HEnum` in the first snippet below). I can't use a plain enumeration because each enum value could have a different type (though the container class will be the same): `Key[A]`. I'd like to be able to construct the enum roughly like this:

```
class Key[A](val name: String)

object A extends HEnum {
  val a = new Key[String]("a")
  val b = new Key[Int]("b")
  val c = new Key[Float]("c")
}
```

And then I'd like to be able to perform more or less basic `HList` operations like:

```
A.find[String] // returns the first element with type Key[String]
A.find("b") // returns the first element with name "b", type should (hopefully) be Key[Int]
```

So far I've been playing with an `HList` as the underlying data structure, but constructing one with the proper type has proven difficult. My most successful attempt looks like this:

```
class Key[A](val name: String)
object Key {
  def apply[A, L <: HList](name: String, l: L): (Key[A], Key[A] :: L) = {
    val key = new Key[A](name)
    (key, key :: l)
  }
}

object A {
  val (a, akeys) = Key[String, HNil]("a", HNil)
  val (b, bkeys) = Key[Int, Key[String] :: HList]("b", akeys)
  val (c, ckeys) = Key[Float, Key[Int] :: HList]("c", bkeys)

  val values = ckeys // use this for lookups, etc

  def find[A]: Key[A] = values.select[A]
  def find[A](name: String): Key[A] = ...
}
```

The problem here is that the interface is clunky. Adding a new value anywhere besides the end of the list of values is error prone and no matter what, you have to manually update `values` any time a new value is introduced. My solution without `HList` involved a `List[Key[_]]` and error prone/unsafe casting to the proper type when needed.

EDIT

I should also mention that the enum example found [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/enum.scala) is not particularly helpful to me (although, if that can be adapted, then great). The added compiler checks for exhaustive pattern matches are nice (and I would ultimately want that) but this enum still only allows a homogeneous collection of enum values.

Comment: You illustrate the behaviour you want in terms of a  `find` operation on `A`, but that doesn't appear in your best attempt, and it's not clear to me from the comments what its semantics are supposed to. It almost suggests a record like structure (in which case, have you looked at shapeless records?) but it's a little hard to tell ... could you elaborate?

Comment: @MilesSabin `find[A]` would basically be an alias for `values.select[A]` in my best attempt (though I haven't actually tried that yet). The case where find takes a `String` would just traverse the list looking for a `Key` with `name ==  str`. I suspect it would be trickier to get the types right in this case, without some sort of String -> type mapping, or at least an explicit type parameter for passing to `values.filter[A]` before looking for the specific `Key[A]`. I have not looked into shapeless records. When I get a moment I'll do some research on those.

Comment: @MilesSabin I've updated my question so that my best attempt is more clear in regards to how it relates to what I've specified.